# ffmpeg -progress parameter not POST-ing any data

Tags: ffmpeg

I have noticed that the ffmpeg -progress parameter doesn't work with URLs. It only works with files.

For eaxmple:

```
ffmpeg -progress log_file.txt -i http://123.123.123.123:8888/live -c copy -f mpegts out.ts
```

works and log_file.txt is filled with data.

While

```
ffmpeg -progress http://127.0.0.1:8888/progress.php -i http://123.123.123.123:8888/live -c copy -f mpegts out.ts
```

does not post any data to http://127.0.0.1:8888/progress.php script.

It's not a web server configuration issue because:

```
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://127.0.0.1:9790/progress.php
```

creates a file with the $_POST array content:

> Array (
>       [param1] => value1
>       [param2] => value2 )

Does -progress really make ffmpeg to post data to urls?

Answer (score 0):

It sends a stream (file stream?). I am using ASP.NET Core and Stream.ReadToEnd() throws Exception.

But this code works for me:

```
ffmpeg -progress http://localhost:8002/progress/send

[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProgressController : ControllerBase
{
    private List<string> _log = new List<string>();

    [Route("send"), HttpPost]
    public void Send()
    {
        string line;

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                do
                {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    _log.Add(line);
                }
                while (line != "progress=end");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```